# Display percent by category in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, percentage

I have a dataset in tableau where I would like to show the percent of each category.

Data

```
free    use type    date
10      5   A1      1/1/2021
20      1   A1      1/1/2021
40      2   B2      1/1/2021
60      3   B2      1/1/2021
```

Desired

```
   type      %

   A1      50%
   B2      50%
```

Doing

[image]

```
SUM( [type] ) / SUM( [type] )
```

However, because 'type' is a string, the calculation is not successful.
Is there a way to showcase a groupby and to display the percent?
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the % of count of rows of each `type`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are trying to get the percent of rows per "type", you can

1. Drag your "Book1.csv (Count)" to your Text marks card
2. From the marks card, click *Percent of Total*

Alternatively you can create a calculated field containing
`COUNT([Book1.csv]) / TOTAL(COUNT([Book1.csv]))`

[image: Example output from Superstore Dataset]

Comment: To fully specify how to compute the percentages (or other table calcs) you may need to also change the default partitioning and addressing — either via the Compute Using menu item above for simpler cases, or by the Edit Table Calculation ... menu item for the general case. Often the default setting is sufficient, but if not experiment with Compute Using and in the extreme case, read the help to learn how table calcs work.

Answer (score -1):

Please try using

```
count([type])/running_sum(count([type]))
```

as a calculated field and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you- it is SUM right and not rsum? - says rsum is unknown function

Comment: using: count([type])/sum(count([type]))  - says this is already an aggregation, getting a calculation error

Comment: oops my bad!! also you can try this 

count([type]) / avg({fixed [date]:count([type])})

this is called LOD functions

Comment: Hard to be certain, but I think he is calculating percentages of the field [use] instead of just counting records. You can calculate percentages with LOD calcs, but its often easier and just as efficient to use table calcs to compute percentages.